# Registering instances of unknown lifetime

Tags: c#, design-patterns, optimization

Let's assume we have 3 different assemblies

***Common assembly***

```
public abstract class ContextBase
{
}

public abstract class ContextManager<T> where T: ContextBase
{
    // contains all the context managing logic.
    public T FindContext()
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

***Application specific assembly 2:***

```
public class SpecialContext : ContextBase
{
    // custom properties specific to this type of context
}

public class SpecialContextManager : ContextManager<SpecialContext>
{
    // inherits most of the logic from its base class but has some
    // overrides to achieve a slightly different behavior
}
```

***Application specific assembly 3:***

```
public class OtherContext : ContextBase
{
    // custom properties specific to this type of context
}

public class OtherContextManager : ContextManager<OtherContext>
{
    // inherits most of the logic from its base class but has some
    // overrides to achieve a slightly different behavior
}
```

The motivation for the abstract generic ContextManager class is, that each ContextManager keeps a static collection of objects specific for the given type T. Of course you could have done something like that Dictionary>.. but I liked the generic base class approach more.

**Question**
Now I want to make a GUI to show/find all contexts. This means all kinds of contexts.
I don't want to write a GUI for each application in each application assembly.
I was thinking of a "common GUI" which shows me all currently active Contexts no matter what type they are (It would be cool to know the type though to show some more detailed information in the GUI). I can obviously find all the contexts using the respective ContextManager instances - but how to I get a grip on them?

This is what I thought of (and rejected in terms of bad design):

```
public static class CmInstanceMonitor
{
    private static List<ContextManager<ContextBase>> _contextMgrs = new List<ContextManager<ContextBase>>;

    public static void RegisterInstance(ContextManager<ContextBase> cm)
    {
        // probably I should make sure I don't add the same object twice
        // unfortunately I cannot use the Type yet as this method is invoked
        // by the base class ctor() :(
        _contextMgrs .Add(cm);
     }
}
```

This way my ContextManager probably lives forever because of the static object that holds a reference to it. Not what I intended. And putting some code into the ContextManager finalizer probably won't do any good because the object will not be GC'ed anyway because of the static reference.

*I'm stuck!* :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Weak References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx). This allows you to maintain a list of all managers without having an impact on Garbage Collection.

However, using generics has some drawbacks in this case. The class `SpecialContextManager` can be cast to `ContextManager<SpecialContext>`. That's fine. However, this class cannot be converted to `ContextManager<ContextBase>`, because those are two different classes. Therefore, you cannot call 
`RegisterInstance(ContextManager<ContextBase>)` passing a concrete manager. So you could either store `objects` (or `WeakReferences` to `objects`) in your list or go with a different approach (e.g. getting all classes via reflection). But then again, the return type of a method that retrieves all managers must be `object` in some way.